# What is a signed number?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, terminology, computer-science, binary

> When is the meaning of "signed number"?

A signed number simply means a number that is negative, correct? Sorry if this seems like a stupid question but I'm just starting to get deep into mathematics/computer science. Thanks!

Comment: It means that the number **might** be negative. It reflects how a value is assigned to a particular bit sequence.

Comment: This term has different meanings in mathematics and in computer science. In mathematics it indicates the direction of the number. In computer science it typically comes as a format that allows to represent positive/negative numbers, and that dictates how various arithmetic operations between them should be conducted.

Comment: Oh sorry. From a binary/computer science perspective

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

If you have an 8 bit number, there are 256 possible bit patterns,
$00000000,00000001,...,11111111$.

There are two 'usual' assignments of values to these bit patterns, to be explicit I will use C types.

An unsigned integer
`uint_8`: $00000000 \to 0$, $00000001 \to 1,..., 11111111 \to 255$.

A signed integer `int_8`: $00000000 \to 0$, $ 00000001 \to 1,...,0111111 \to 127$, $1000000 \to -128$,$ 10000001 \to -127,..., 11111111 \to -1$.

The two 8-bit types can represent the same number of values (256), but in the
signed case, roughly half of these represent negative numbers.

In the above, the signed representation has the nice property that the 8 bit
representation of a suitable negative value is the twos complement representation of the corresponding positive value.

Comment: Perfect. Just what I was looking for. Thanks!